# How to recursively split a 2D array into a tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion, tensor

I have turned dataframe that has a tuple of length 2 as index

```
          1   2  -1
(0, 1)    0   1   0
(0, 2)    1   0   0
(0, -1)   0   0   0
(1, 1)    1   0   0
(1, 2)    0   1   0
(1, -1)   1   1   1
```

into numpy 2D array and managed to split it to 3D array(in regards to the first value) by split funcion:

```
arr = np.array(np.array_split(arr,2))
```

with result

```
[[[0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]

[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]]
```

I want to make a function to do the split even further, for example, to create 5D tensor from (0,0,0,0) (length 4) indices.

Any idea on how to do this recursively?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to generate sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

def create_fake_data_frame(nlevels = 2, ncols = 3):
    result = pd.DataFrame(
        index=itertools.product(*(nlevels * [[0, 1]])),
        data=np.arange(ncols*2**nlevels).reshape(2**nlevels, ncols)
    )
    result = convert_index_of_tuples_to_multiindex(result)
    return result

def convert_index_of_tuples_to_multiindex(df):
    return df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index))

# Increase nlevels to get dataframes with more levels in their MultiIndex
df = create_fake_data_frame(nlevels=3)
print(df)
```

This is the result:

```
        0   1   2
0 0 0   0   1   2
    1   3   4   5
  1 0   6   7   8
    1   9  10  11
1 0 0  12  13  14
    1  15  16  17
  1 0  18  19  20
    1  21  22  23
```

Then, modify the dataframe in such a way that each row contains a single
column, whose value is a list of the values in the corresponding row of
the original dataframe:

```
def data_frame_with_single_column_of_lists(df):
    if len(df.columns) <= 1:
        return df
    result = df.apply(collapse_columns_into_lists, axis=1)
    return result

def collapse_columns_into_lists(s):
    result = s.copy()
    result['lists'] = result.values.tolist()
    result = result[['lists']]
    return result

df = data_frame_with_single_column_of_lists(df)
print(df)
```

The output will be like this:

```
              lists
0 0 0     [0, 1, 2]
    1     [3, 4, 5]
  1 0     [6, 7, 8]
    1   [9, 10, 11]
1 0 0  [12, 13, 14]
    1  [15, 16, 17]
  1 0  [18, 19, 20]
    1  [21, 22, 23]
```

Finally, use the following code to get a tensor

```
def increase_list_nesting_by_removing_an_index_level(df):
    def list_of_lists(series):
        result = series.to_frame().set_index(series.index.droplevel(-1))
        result = result.apply(lambda x: x['lists'], axis=1).to_frame()
        result = [x[0] for x in result.values.tolist()]
        return result
    grouped = df.groupby(df.index.droplevel(-1))
    result = grouped.agg(list_of_lists)
    if type(result.index[0]) == tuple:
        result = convert_index_of_tuples_to_multiindex(result)
    return result

def tensor_from_data_frame(df):
    if df.index.nlevels <= 1:
        return np.array([i[0] for i in df.values])

    result = increase_list_nesting_by_removing_an_index_level(df)
    result = tensor_from_data_frame(result)
    return result

tensor = tensor_from_data_frame(df)
print(tensor)
```

The result will be like this:

```
[[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]]

  [[ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]]]


 [[[12 13 14]
   [15 16 17]]

  [[18 19 20]
   [21 22 23]]]]
```